# AngularJS - Function declared in child directive called in the parent controller

Tags: angularjs

Call a function on **parent controller** that is declared in is **child directive**.

Parent controller HTML

```
<div ng-click="testFunction()"></div>
```

Parent controller js

```
  $scope.testFunction = function(){
    $scope.functionFromChildDirective()
  }
```

Child directive js

```
function TestDirective() {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
      },  
      templateUrl: '',
      controller: function($scope) {
        "ngInject";

        $scope.functionFromChildDirective = function(){
          console.log("TEST")
        }

      }
    }
  }

  export default {
    name: 'testDirective',
    fn: TestDirective
  };
```

Comment: Attempting to call a function from a child component kind of goes against AngularJS' philosophy and the principle of separation of concerns. One cleaner and less tightly coupled approach would be using custom events. [AngularJS Docs here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the empty scope deceleration, by defining it you are creating a new isolate scope. If you don't declare the scope in the directive definition object it will just inherit the parents scope. However with this approach the child directive can only be used once (i.e can't be repeated) as each instance of will just overwrite the $scope.functionFromChildDirective property.

Comment: Hello run, I need to have an isolated scope to pass another function from parent to child, I just deleted to simplify my question. There's no other way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ng-ref` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef) to bind the controller to a parent variable:

```
<test-directive ng-ref="testAPI">
</test-directive>
```

```
function TestDirective() {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
      },  
      templateUrl: '',
      controller: function() {
        this.testFn = function(){
          console.log("TEST")
        }

      }
    }
  }
```

To invoke it:

```
<div ng-click="testAPI.testFn()"></div>
```

The `ngRef` directive tells AngularJS to assign the controller of a component (or a directive) to the given property in the current scope.

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-ref Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have not have the opportunity to test it yet, so I cannot accept as a correct answer, but I will do it soon. thanks for the help